# crm 4 to crm 2013 upgrade - saved views migration

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are in the process of planning a CRM 4 to CRM 2013 upgrade (via CRM 2011 I believe). Does anyone know if the saved views are or can be migrated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own console app which will copy/re-create the views from the CRM 4 environment in the CRM 2013.

See http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/crm-2011-creating-view-records-shared-user/
for creating views through code.

However, as one user can only see his personal views (this happens when you try to view the personal views through the SDK code as well), each user will need to run this console app separately, with his own login details.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the Saved Views (through Advanced Find interface) to Excel and attempt re-importing them after upgrading the organization, *if* the upgrade process doesn't keep them (I have no prior experience with upgrading 4 to 2011 to 2013).

Answer (score -1):

They should upgrade just fine, but as the other have pointed out, better safe than sorry. 
I've done a few upgrades and haven't hit any issues with save viwes. (CRM4-2011, CRM4-2013, CRM2011-2013 and even a CRM3-2011 which was a bit more trouble...)